# Not able to convert back from binary to int using rnn package in R

Tags: r, recurrent-neural-network

In rnn package, int can be converted to binary using int2bin. Like

```
a= int2bin(8)
```

Now when we use `bin2int` on a, it should give 8. Simply
`bin2int(int2bin(8))` should be 8. But it is giving something else: 134217728.

Why? What is the correct approach to convert it back to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can not access rnn package because it had some bugs reported
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnn/index.html page. i suggest u try this.

```
library(binaryLogic)
as.binary(8) ///[1] 1 0 0 0
as.intfrombinary <- function(x) {
returnvalue<-
sum(2^(which(rev(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "")) == 1))-1))
return(returnvalue)
}
as.intfrombinary(as.binary(8)) ///[1] 8
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped. It gave me the idea of creating my own function as per my own needs.